# Where can i get Remote Blob storage sample database?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL server 2008 , remote blob storage feature.

http://www.codeplex.com/sqlrbs

I came across this site. They are mentioning about sample database in this site, can you please suggest where i can get the RBS database.

Pls suggest ,Where i can get more information on RBS.

Thanks in advance.
Sudhakar.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the SQL Server 2008 samples are shared here:
http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=18407

It may have the database you are looking for.